# Lan connecting to a router thomson tg585 v8 to give internet to wifi localy

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, lubuntu

I have lubuntu 10.04 install on a desktop computer and have wifi internet connection, i want by Lan connecting to a router Thomson tg585 v8 to give internet to wifi local.....(laptop using Ubuntu 12.10 , android phone,Playstation,e.t.c)

Comment: i have tried brigde the thomson  and make a wifi network but then i cannot connect through the lan

Comment: This question is very ambiguous and difficult to understand - you may get a better response if you explain your setup and exactly what you are trying to do, and what is not working.  (For a start, what does the ubuntu install have to do with anything, are you wanting to relay the connection via A PC ?)  What do you mean by  "I want by lan connecting to a router..."

Comment: ok let me explain...i have a desktop computer(pc1) running lubuntu 10.04 this (pc1) has connection to the internet by wifi.i want to give internet through lan to the thomson tg585 and then i want the the thomson to work as an access point!!! i hope i explained better.